# Django url pattern with or without <projectName> as path to view?

Tags: python, django, urlconf

I'm new to Django and been reading the http://djangobook.com and finds that the following two patterns work the same way with no hiccups for project named `mysite` and `views.py` on the project root with a function named `hello`.

```
(r'^hello/$', 'mysite.views.hello')
(r'^hello/$', 'views.hello)
```

May I know what's the practice like? with or without the proceeding Project namespace? And if I may, why?

`''` is the prefix for these patterns.

Comment: the prefix for the code above is `''`

Comment: I would opt for the one that doesn't include the project name, as that encourages more reuse.

The djangobook.com is quite out of date, I think you would get more out of the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) on the main site.

Comment: @MikeHan: Please do not add comments.  Please **update** the question to be complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fisrt one is because the mysite dir is in your python path;

the second one is because when your run the project, the current path will add to python path.